# War file not getting registered on specified context path when url pattern is specified as /*

Tags: java, jboss, web.xml

I am doing a deployment to Jboss EAR 6.4

My war files contains **jboss-web.xml** as per the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_8_0.xsd">
    <context-root>/myapp</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

My **web.xml** file contains the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>myappadmin</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Once i deploy it then it doesnt get registered. Ideally i want to expose it to

```
http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.html
```

but it doesn't work. Although if i change my web.xml to have url-pattern as

```
<url-pattern>/myapppath/*</url-pattern>
```

Then it successfully registers it to 
 `http://localhost:8080/myapp/myapppath/index.html`

Can you please advice on how can i register myapp on http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.html without a url pattern?

Comment: Try removing `context-root` from `jboss-web.xml`, default context root should be the name of your war file without extension.

Comment: @RahulYadav Samething. It deploys successfully but says no mapping found as soon as i hit  http://localhost:8080/myapp/index.html after removing jboss-web.xml and renaming the file to myapp.war and deploying.